# android time delay between views

Tags: android, time, delay

I'm not sure, what is stopping this from working. I have the code setup to cause a 3 second time delay but the View isn't working, it stays black and then after 3 seconds switches to the next screens. I think, I am doing the time delay and something hasn't been called within Android to display the layout...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    setContentView(R.layout.team);
}

protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();        
    while(game)
    {
        now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (now - start >= 5000)
        {
            game = false;
            Intent about = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
            startActivity(about);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to implement a Screen with few seconds delay and then start your main Application. Just like a Splash Screen Before the Main Application Starts Right?

Then this will help you!

```
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    /** set time to splash out */
    final int welcomeScreenDisplay = 4000;
    /** create a thread to show splash up to splash time */
    Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {

    int wait = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
    super.run();
    /**
    * use while to get the splash time. Use sleep() to increase
    * the wait variable for every 100L.
    */
    while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
    sleep(100);
    wait += 100;
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
    } finally {
    /**
    * Called after splash times up. Do some action after splash
    * times up. Here we moved to another main activity class
    */
    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
    finish();
    }
    }
    };
    welcomeThread.start();
}
```

This is a Screen for 4 seconds of Delay.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the Timer class to launch the new activity.